# 'su' command in Docker returns 'must be run from terminal'

Tags: linux, docker

I'm developing a docker environment for teaching purposes and need to be able to switch users inside docker.

I set up the 'user' user with a password but when I try to switch to it with su, I get "su must be run from terminal".

I get this if I try to ssh into the docker and also by issuing commands through a php shell (an apache service is running on the Docker instance).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd be interested to know more about your use case / setup. Running SSH in the container is an anti-pattern. Are you needing to change user on the fly (while you are 'in' the container?) or as part of a build process (using a Dockerfile?).

Comment: If you Google this error message, there are several solutions.

Comment: Thank you warmoverflow actual help would be appreciated. I did find a workaround running python but would need a consistent solution.

Comment: JHarris I'm not sure what the original use of docker is but I'm using it for a fairly specific special scenario. I'm building PoC vulnerabilities in them to showcase software (in)security.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you are ssh-ing in or going in via php your session is not being allocated a pty. I have used each of the following solutions:

**ANSWER 1: use ssh -t or ssh -tt to get pty allocated when logging in using ssh:**

I had great fun getting commands to run right due to ptys when running sessions like this: jenkins shell -> ssh driver -> ssh test -> docker exec. 
Good answer here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105422/command-must-be-run-from-a-terminal

"Try the -t option to ssh. If that does not work try -tt."

"-t Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty."

**ANSWER 2: use docker run -t ... and docker exec -it**

Use the -t and -it options to allocate pty in your docker exec session.

Also with docker exec you can simply use the -u  option to login to container as different users and avoid using su. e.g.

```
$ docker exec -u root -it small_hypatia bash
```

There is a good question and answer on this here:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8631

**ANSWER 3: use python to spawn a pty in your shell**

Quite a cute hack :)

```
jenkins@e9fbe94d4c89:~$ su -
su: must be run from a terminal

$ echo "import pty; pty.spawn('/bin/bash')" > /tmp/asdf.py
$ python /tmp/asdf.py

$ su -
Password: 

root@e9fbe94d4c89:~#
```

Comment: As a one liner: `python -c "import pty; pty.spawn('/bin/bash')"`

Answer (score 9):

This solution work by using 'script' command from the 'bsdutiles' package that setup a pty (a terminal). The 'sleep' command is there to prevent sending the password before the 'su' command is ready to read it. The 'tail' command remove the "Password:" input line issued by 'su'.

```
 sh -c "sleep 1; echo rootpassword" | script -qc 'su -c whoami - root' | tail -n +2
```

Beware that the rootpassword could be see in many ways (history, ps, /proc/, etc...). Start the command with a space to at least avoid history recording.

Comment: Might want to change the script part to `script /dev/null -qc [...]` to prevent `script` from saving the output to a file called `typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec) instead of `su` the issue with tty completely vanishes since it calls execvp directly instead of forking like `su` does.

[Gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) is another similar alternative.